# How to insert WP post title from accordion to modal box

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I create a Bootstrap Accordion from Wordpress posts. The Accordion is created without problems.
Each element of the accordion has a title (as the title of the Wordpress post).
Each element has a button that displays the modal box.

I would like the modal box title to be exactly the same as the title of the accordion element from which it is called.

The Accordion is created using the while loop.
I do not know if the modal box HTML should also be included in this loop?
Perhaps I should keep the titles in the table from which I will obtain the appropriate title depending on which button is clicked?

This is the problematic title in modal box:

```
<h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
```

which currently only shows the first title of accordion element, regardless of which button of the accordion element is clicked

My code is here:

```
<!-- accordion -->
      <div id="accordion-career" class="accordion" role="tablist">
        <!-- card 1 -->
        <?php
          $count = 1;
         ?>
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'oferty_pracy', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="career-acc-<?php echo $count; ?>">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#career-coll-<?php echo $count; ?>" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="career-coll-<?php echo $count;?>">
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span><i class="fas fa-lg fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div id="career-coll-<?php echo $count; ?>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="career-acc-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-parent="#accordion-career">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- body of the accordion element -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 career-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="global-btn btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#careerModal"><span class="nav-text">Aplikuj na to stanowisko</span><i class="fa-xs fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    <a href="<?php the_field('plik_oferty'); ?>" role="button" class="global-btn btn"><span class="nav-text">Pobierz w pdf</span><i class="fa-xs fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Career MODAL -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="careerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Aplikujesz na stanowisko:</h5>
                <h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- FORM body of the modal -->
              </div>
              <!-- end of form -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of modal -->
        <?php
          $count++;
          endwhile;
        ?>
        <!-- end -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of accordion -->
```

Comment: I think I managed to solve the problem :)

I added a number in the above code, so every element of accordion has its modal box :)

- for the button:
data-target = "# careerModal <? php echo $ count;?>

and for the modal box:
id = "careerModal <? php echo $ count;?>

Comment: this is a job for javascript. You need to run a function on "click" to grab the title of the one that was clicked and populate the modal title with that title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give an ID to the title element of each card, such as `title1` for card 1, `title2` for card 2...
2. Give an ID to the MODAL header element, such as `modalHeader`
3. Trigger a JavaScript function when you click the button of a card
4. The JavaScript function copy the title from the card to the MODAL header

for example

```
function refreshModalTitle(postId) {
    var title = document.getElementById('title' + postId).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML= title ;
}
```